# How can I open File location in django project

Tags: django, file, django-models, django-views, location

I tried to open file location in django project with this code.

```
<a href="C:\Users\development\SmartSearch Project\Data" target="_explorer.exe">Open Location</a>
```

It's working in normal web pages. its not working in django project.

Answer (score 0):

So here how it works

1. Add static folder in your project folder (not in project folder that contains settings.py)
2. Add the bellow code to your settings.py (you can find it under project folder)

   ```
   STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

   STATIC_URL = '/static/'

   STATICFILES_DIRS = [STATIC_DIR,]
   ```
3. Then copy the files in static folder that you want access
4. Run these commands on terminal

   ```
   python manage.py collectstatic
   ```
5. Now change your HTML mark up to this

   ```
   href="{% static 'after static folder define route here' %}" target="_explorer.exe">Open Location
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind help..
It's showing "A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator."
Please help me out.

Comment: Can you show me the snapshot of the error and the log